# Unable to connect to DigitalOcean Postgres DB with TLS in Deno

Tags: postgresql, ssl, digital-ocean, deno

I have the following code, but it's unable to connect to the DB

```
import { Client } from 'https://deno.land/x/postgres@v0.17.0/mod.ts';

const client = new Client({
  hostname: '<url>.ondigitalocean.com',
  port: 25060,
  user: 'doadmin',
  database: 'defaultdb',
  tls: {
    enabled: true,
    enforce: true,
    caCertificates: [await Deno.readTextFile('./ca-certificate.crt')],
  },
  password: Deno.env.get('DB_PASSWORD') || config().DB_PASSWORD,
});
await client.connect();
```

I get the following error running my app, even if i pass the `--cert` option or `--unsafely-ignore-certificate-errors`:

```
Sending fatal alert DecodeError
error: Uncaught Error: The certificate used to secure the TLS connection is invalid.
```

Comment: What library are you using to try to connect? I'm not seeming an import here.

Comment: its postgres@v0.17.0, thanks edited it with the import